# PartToc looks bad (pagebreak etc.)

Tags: minitoc

Wonderful Good Evening,
I have one problem with the minitoc-Package, which I'm using for parttocs.
I have one main-texFile with one titlepage and one overall-toc and after this, I'm importing ten files with stories, separated with \addpart{}-Tags.
Now I want to have a parttoc for every imported file.
My problem is, that every part-toc of a file, which have more than 30 sections looks very bad, it is divided in **3 pages**.
On page one, there is the title "Inhaltsverzeichnis" (it's german) and a long horizontal line. On the second page there are all section-headings who have place on this page (all the others are cuttet of) and on page three, there is another horizontal line.
I don't know, what is wrong.
My main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=17mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\chead{- \thepage \hspace{1pt} - }
\cfoot{}
\let\raggedpart\centering
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart}
\newcommand*{\extendedpart}[5]{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{large}
    \centering
    #1\par
    \addpart{#2}\refstepcounter{part}
    \vfill
    #3\par
    \vfill
    #4\par
    \vfill
    \textbf{Autor:} #5\par
  \end{large}
  \end{titlepage}
  \parttoc
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{\thepart.\thesection}
\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{large}
\centering
Some information\par
\part*{Title}
\vfill
Description \par
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{picture.jpg}\par
\vfill
\begin{center} \textbf{Author:} ... \end{center}
\end{large}
\end{titlepage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\addpart{Introduction}
\blindtext

\extendedpart{Some information2}{Title2}{Description2}{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{picture2.jpg}}{Author2}
\include{story1}

%and the other nine stories

\end{document}
```

And all of my other files looking like this, only including 40 to 50 sections in each:

```
\section{Title 1}
Some text here.
\section{Title 2}
Some other text here.
```

It's always working if I have in maximum 20 sections per file, but I have more of it.
I hope you can help me and you can understand my Englisch. Thank you very much.

Regards
Malte

Comment: `\parttoc` print a horizontal rule  befor entries but `minitoc` package uses `samepage` environment so all entries go to next page to be in same page and the horizontal rule below go to next page and then new page because of `\include`

Comment: you can try redefine `\renewenvironment{samepage}{}{}` and replace `\include{story1}` with `\input{story1}` in your own responsibility

Comment: `tocloft`, `minitoc` and `scr...` KOMA class -- I am not sure this will work as expected!

Comment: Thank you very much. \renewenvironment{samepage}{}{} is working. Also without replacing include with input.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments